# Display 2 language in bracket for options using ng-options angular js

Tags: angularjs, multilingual, ng-options

I have a selectbox, in that selectbox i need to show 2 language options. 
for example: the option should be like this  **mysore (Mysuru)**. I have used ng-options for this

```
 <select name="citySelect" required="true" ng-options="city.name.en (city.name.de) for city in cities" ng-model="selectedCity" ng-change="centerCity(selectedCity)"></select>
```

i have used **(city.name.de)** in ng-options. that is wrong i know. but i want to know how to use instead of that to display in bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
ng-options="( city.name.en +'('+ city.name.de + ')' ) for city in cities"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. i was just trying some plugin for it